# How do Loop this command?

Tags: command-line, command, cmd

I'm new to this community and new to coding. I'm trying to figure out if there is a way to repeat a command like this

```
CMD /k Taskkill /IM A.exe /F 
CMD /k Taskkill /IM B.exe /F 
CMD /k Taskkill /IM C.exe /F 
CMD /k Taskkill /IM D.exe /F 
CMD /k Taskkill /IM E.exe /F
```

I'm currently using this code to do the same thing

```
:A
Taskkill /IM A.exe /F
Taskkill /IM B.exe /F
Taskkill /IM C.exe /F
Taskkill /IM D.exe /F
Taskkill /IM E.exe /F

Goto A
```

Although the code I'm using can be faulty because the batch program does not execute simultaneously. I need help looking for a way to execute the commands simultaneously in batch or any other kind of language. Your help will be much appreciated.

Comment: How is this related to Java?

Comment: How many times are you trying to loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a loop, be it a `for` or a `while`. Using `goto` for looping is not used anymore in any *modern* language that I can think of! That kind of iteration is used in assembler, or in very primitive scripting/programming languages. Haven't you coded anything in the last, say, 20 years or so? :P

Comment: Thanks for the help and yes, I guess you can call me old school... Haha.

Answer (score 0):

**-** `while` **or** `for` loop will do the work.

**Eg:**

```
while(true){  // Its a infinite loop

dosomething...
dosomething....

}
```

**Or**

```
for(;;){  // Its a infinite loop

    dosomething...
    dosomething....

    }
```